# Why is Java Calendar saying the first Thursday of the month is Week 5?

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to figure out how to make an alarm on a specific day of the week.  Here is sample code that prints what I expect:

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
  System.out.println("Week of month: " + calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)); // Week of month: 1
```

But when I add this to the code I get a result I dont understand:

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY);
  calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
  System.out.println("Week of month: " + calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)); // Week of month: 5
```

I am trying to set an alarm for a specific day in a specific week.  The date today is June 15th, 2013.  Could someone please explain this to me.  Joda time is not an option with what I am doing, so I need to make this work with the regular Java libs.  Thanks for all the help.

#### Editor's note

The above code will return different results based on the date it is run, because `Calendar.getInstance()` returns a Calendar set to the current time.  For an illustration of the problem that is independent of the current time, use this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(1371294000000L);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
System.out.println("Week of month: " + calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)); 
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Which outputs something like this (at least if your default locale is using the Gregorian Calendar):

```
Jun 15, 2013
Jun 13, 2013
Week of month: 5
May 30, 2013
```

Comment: What's your timezone? For me it prints `Week of month: 1`

Comment: Eastern Standard Time.  I am on the Atlantic Coast.  I cleaned my project and ran it again, and still got 5.  Could it have something to do with week 1 not having a Thursday?  When I put 2, 3, 4, 5 in for the week number, I get what I expect.

Comment: I also get "Week of month: 1"  Have you copied exactly what your code was, or did you retype it with a slight difference?

Comment: @jhamm: That's exactly it. This holds true for your locale. Thursday in the first week of this month (June) is May, 30th.

Comment: So how can I programmatically set an alarm in a similar instance where the first week of the month is on a Friday and I want the first Thursday, which is in the second week.  There has to be a beter way!

Comment: Do you want to make a formal answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @jhamm: You can also accept a self written answer ;) I'm not a Locale expert...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is *lenient* by default. If you set it to January 32, it will translate that to Feb 1. Furthermore, the definition of "week" is Locale-specific and a bit confusing.  This is explained in great detail in the JavaDocs linked to above.

In your particular case (or at least in my Locale), a week is defined as starting on Sunday and the "first week of June" is defined as the Sunday through Saturday period that includes June 1.  June 1, 2013, is a Saturday, the last day in week 22 of the year 2013.  Sunday, June 2, 2013, is the first day of week 2 of June, not the second day of week 1.

Since there is no Thursday in week 1 of June, the *lenient* calendar interprets `DAY_OF_WEEK, THURSDAY` to be the Thursday of week 22 of year 2013, which is May 30, 2013, which is week 5 of May, so you get 5 and not 1 in your output.

To set the first Thursday in June, you want:

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JUNE);
 calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY);
 calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
```

`DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` can be a bit confusing.  You use it with `DAY_OF_WEEK` to specify which occurrence of that day in that month you want.  So when `DAY_OF_WEEK` is set to Thursday, `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1` is the first Thursday of the month, `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 2` is the second Thursday of the month, etc.  This is much less Locale-specific or open to (mistaken) interpretation then what days constitute the first week of the month.